# Text above the footer

Tags: footer

I am new to LaTeX and stuck at how to make a footer like shown in the figure:

[image: text above footer]

Help would be appreciated.

## Edit:

When I try to use `\pagestyle{fancy}` my documents runs out of memory (might be due to too many unnecessary packages). I tried using footnote like

```
\footnote{\textcopyright \;Gujrat Institute of Management Sciences\\ 
  PMAS-Arid Agriculture University, Rawalpindi}
```

but that did not work either, and I only want this footer on some specific pages.

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about). That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, because you gave us no MWE your question is not very clear. Because we do not know if you are using an KOMA-Script class or other standard class like `article` I simply guess you are using an class `article`. Then you can use package `fancyhdr` for creating headers and footers for every page of the document. Please note that situation changes if you are using KOMA-Script ...

To be able to use a special header-footer-combination for a special page(s) with command `\thispagestyle{copyright}` you need to define the style `copyright` like this:

```
\fancypagestyle{copyright}{%
  \fancyhf{} % empty header and footer
  \fancyfoot{% 
    \centering
    \textbf{Gujrat Institute of Management Sciences}\\
    \textbf{PMAS-Arid Agriculture University, Rawalpindi}\\
    \thepage\\
    \raggedright\footnotesize
    \textcopyright\ Gujrat Institute of Management Sciences\\
    PMAS-Arid Agriculture University, Rawalpindi\\
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
}
```

Because your question is not very clear if you really need all the shown lines in your image I simply added all of them. Change the content of command `\fancyfoot` for your needs ... In the following MWE I added package `showframe` to visualize the used typing area and margins. Please see that on page 2 with your `copyright` style the footer changes the position of the pagenumber too.

With this MWE (see important code marked with `<=====`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % <================ to visualize typing area and margins
\usepackage{blindtext} % <================ adding dummy text into document
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{copyright}{%
  \fancyhf{} % empty header and footer
  \fancyfoot{% 
    \centering
    \textbf{Gujrat Institute of Management Sciences}\\
    \textbf{PMAS-Arid Agriculture University, Rawalpindi}\\
    \thepage\\
    \raggedright\footnotesize
    \textcopyright\ Gujrat Institute of Management Sciences\\
    PMAS-Arid Agriculture University, Rawalpindi\\
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
}

\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\clearpage % <======================= new page 2
\thispagestyle{copyright} % <======== style copyright only used on this page 2!
\blindtext

\clearpage % <======================= new page 3 with standard style fancy
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

you get the following pages:

[image: resulting pdf]

If that is not what you need, please register your account and edit your question by adding more information to explain better your issue ...

Answer (score 2):

With fancyhdr package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancyfoot{
    \centering
    \textbf{Institute}\\
    \textbf{University}\\
    \thepage\\
    \raggedright
    \footnotesize
    Copyright ...\\
    PMAS\\
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}%
}


\begin{document}

zzz

\end{document}
```

[image]